# Automatically change year in Excel in already available dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am working on a daily stocks data that have dates that range from 2016 to 2000. The problem is the the data I have imported have converted all the years to "2016". The dates are in descending order. When the dates move from Januray to the next year's december, the year does not change.
Currently I am using date function. But I have to manually change the formula to the next year whenever the year changes. I want to automate this process as I have to work on alot of data that has this same issue.
**Things to keep in mind**

1. Dates are in descending order from april 2016 to january 2000
2. As the data is of daily stock prices, months in the data does not necesarily starts from 1st or ends at 31st. E.g one company's last date of december data was 14th in 2010.
3. I want the dates and month to remaing same but the year to change whenever the ending date (not always 31st or 30th) of december comes.

Your help will save me alot of time and I will be grateful Thank You in advane.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data starts in 2nd row:

- copy B2 to C2
- from C3 use this formula: `=DATE(YEAR(C2)-IF(B3>B2,1,0),MONTH(B3),DAY(B3))`

[image]

Comment: Yes sir, it worked. Thank you very very much.